# Spectral symmetry of a certain structured matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

I have a matrix

$$ A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a & d & c\\ \bar a & 0 & b & d \\ \bar d  & \bar b & 0 & a \\ \bar c & \bar d & \bar a & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

As you can see, the matrix is always self-adjoint for any $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb C$.

But it has a funny property (that I found by playing with some numbers):

If $a,b,c$ are arbitrary real numbers and **also** $d$ is real, then the spectrum of $A$ is in general not symmetric with respect to zero. To illustrate this, we take $d := 2$, $a := 5$, $b := 3$, $c := 4$ then the eigenvalues are

$$\sigma(A):=\{10.5178, -6.54138, -3.51783, -0.458619\}$$

But once I take $d \in i \mathbb R$, the spectrum becomes immediately symmetric. In fact, $d := 2 i$, $a := 5$, $b := 3$, $c := 4$ leads to eigenvalues

$$\sigma(A)=\{-9.05607, 9.05607, -0.993809, 0.993809\}$$

Is there any particular symmetry that only exists for $d \in i\mathbb R$ that implies this nice inflection symmetry?

I am less interested in a brute-force computation of the spectrum than of an explanation of what symmetry causes the inflection symmetry.

Comment: Is it symmetric for all choices of $a$, $b$ and $c$ (real and or complex)?

Comment: @M.Winter good question, now I am tempted to say that it actually only works for $a,b,c$ real.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For real $a,b,c$ and imaginary $d$ the matrix $A$ has *chiral symmetry*, meaning it anticommutes with a matrix $X$ that squares to the identity:
$$X=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
 0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
 0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
 i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;XA+AX=0,\;\;X^2=I.$$
Hence the spectrum of $A$ has $\pm$ symmetry:
$$\det (\lambda-A)=\det(\lambda X^2-XAX)=\det(\lambda+X^2A)=\det(\lambda+A),$$
so if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then also $-\lambda$.

Comment: how did you get $\det(\lambda I-A)=\det(\lambda X^2-XAX)$?

Comment: Since $X^2=1$, you can multiply $\det(\lambda-A)$ with $\det X^2=(\det X)^2$; and since the product of determinants is the determinant of the matrix product, you have $\det(\lambda-A)=\det[X(\lambda-A)X]=\det(\lambda X^2-XAX)$.

Comment: great! a useful trick in evaluating some determinants

Answer (score 16):

An equivalent trick : Let $J:= \operatorname{diag}(1,i,-1,-i)$. Then $J^*AJ=iB$ where $B$ is real and skew-symmetric. Hence the spectrum of $iB$ (thus that of $A$) comes by pairs $\pm\lambda$.